# Python Mahalanobis distance multidimensional z-score

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats, mahalanobis

I want a performance score, like a z-score, for two-dimensional data around a known fixed point. I think I want the Mahalanobis distance now, rather than z-scores in each direction. But I don't have two vectors, I have a 2 x N array of positions of N points in x-y, and a fixed 2D point I want to compare it to. I looked at this example:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
iv = [[1, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 1, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 1]]
distance.mahalanobis([1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], iv)
```

for calculating in Python, but I don't know what my iv should be. And do I just put my known point, like:

```
distance.mahalanobis([1,4],iv)
```

? Thanks

Comment: The Mahalanobis distance, is between point p, and distribution/points D. If you have 2xN arrays of positions, it is not clear what you want to define as point p (or many many p giving many distances) and distribution D (set of points). One way, would be to define the space S as all pairs (i,j) and you want to define the distance for each point to S itself.

Comment: Yes, so I have one fixed point p say (1,4) and I want the Mahalanobis distance for N 2D points to the point p. I just don't understand how to use the scipy stats function for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am going to create random data in `X` of dimension 2, which will define the distribution,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

from scipy.spatial import distance

X = np.random.normal(size=(100,2), loc=(1,4) )
```

Now you can use the Mahalanobis distance, of the first point with

```
distance.mahalanobis( X[0] , np.mean(X,axis=0), scipy.linalg.inv(np.cov(X.T)) )
```

and for instance with your own `p = (1,4)` with

```
distance.mahalanobis( np.array([1,4]) , np.mean(X,axis=0), scipy.linalg.inv(np.cov(X.T)) )
```

If your `N` is too large, COV matrix might be too expensive too calculate and you can sample.

---

Change the size of `N` from 100 to 1000 indeed won't have much effect, as the sample of the same distribution simply gets larger. To feel the effect of different parameters best is to plot some pictures and try different points `p`. Alternative is to generate `X` around different mean, i.e. `X = np.random.normal(size=(100,2), loc=(2,10) )` which if you keep your `p` `(1,4)` has effect as well

Comment: That's great, thankyou! I did play with the scale of the normal and increased the N, but the distance didn't change as much as I was expecting, even for scale=100, I'm not sure I understand that part, will the distance always be approx [0,1] like a z-score?

`X = np.random.normal(size=(1000,2), loc=(1,4), scale=0.01)
m = distance.mahalanobis( np.array([1,4]) , np.mean(X,axis=0), scipy.linalg.inv(np.cov(X.T)) )
print(m)

X = np.random.normal(size=(1000,2), loc=(1,4), scale=1)
m = distance.mahalanobis( np.array([1,4]) , np.mean(X,axis=0), scipy.linalg.inv(np.cov(X.T)) )`

Comment: To get the Mahalanobis for all points, would it be best to use `np.sum(distance.mahalanobis( np.array([1,4]) , (X,axis=0), scipy.linalg.inv(np.cov(X.T)) )` as above, or `distance.mahalanobis( np.array([1,4]) , np.mean(X,axis=0), scipy.linalg.inv(np.cov(X.T)) ))` I have checked and they give different results (with the /100 included too). Here [link] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351549/maximum-likelihood-estimators-multivariate-gaussian) looks like sum would be correct, before combining with the log of the covariance matrix?